# UE5 - stop hiding the Content Draw

Tags: gui, unreal

Semi-Solution:

Going to Window > Layout > UE4 Classic Layout opens out the content browser and other stuff without them closing down again. However, I'm still not sure how to set it to stay or not stay without just resetting the layout.

---

The content draw, content browser, details, world settings and other stuff are all hidden in Unreal Engine 5. Can I stop them hiding so I can just see them?

I had it so they wouldn't hide a few days ago, but now they always hide and it's really annoying. I think there's a key or a setting somewhere but I've failed to find it, in UE5 or by searching.

Anyone know how to stop it doing that? I just want it to stay up. It's really tedious right now.

Comment: what changed from when they didnt hide to now when they always hide? did you accidentally press the big red "hide content draw" button introduced in ue5..?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Where is that "hide content draw" button? I can't find it. I have the one that opens it temporarily, but I can't get it to stay on screen. I expect I did press something but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 or perhaps there is no 'big red button' and you're just being unhelpfully flippant.

Comment: Did you look carefully, it's definitely there?

Comment: Can you link an image, or just someone's tutorial where it's visible at some point you could point out?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/quE1ykX.png Odd choice from the UI design team sure, but this should be hard to miss?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 This is serious, I've looked but I still don't see it. I've looked everywhere! See? https://i.imgur.com/ycaI10a.png